# benefits of temporary table in oracle over an ordinary table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I came accross creating the temporary table in oracle. But could not understand the best use of this.
Can someone help me to understand what is the features and benefits of using a temporary table in Oracle `(create temporary table temp_table)` over an ordinary table `(create table temp_table)` 
)

Comment: Temp table is stores in the temp tablespace is is used mostly for storing data for the duration of the session or for a limited amount of time.

Answer (score 8):

From the [concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#CNCPT211):

> A temporary table definition persists in the same way as a permanent
>   table definition, but the data exists only for the duration of a
>   transaction or session. Temporary tables are useful in applications
>   where a result set must be held temporarily, perhaps because the
>   result is constructed by running multiple operations.

[And](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#CBBBADBI):

> Data in a temporary table is private to the session, which means that
>   each session can only see and modify its own data.

So one aspect is that the data is private to your session. Which is also true of uncommitted  data in a permanent table, but with a temporary table the data can persist and yet stay private across a commit (based on the `on commit` clause on creation).

Another aspect is that they use [temporary segments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/logical.htm#i5696), which means you generate much less redo and undo overhead using a temporary table than you would if you put the same data temporarily into a permanent table, optionally updated it, and then removed it when you'd finished with it. You also avoid contention and locking issues if more than one session needs its own version of the temporary data.

Comment: Thanks Alex for nice explanation. So if there is one temp table used by multiple sessions, e.g. multiple logged in users, then how could they behave? 

Ok, let me explain the scenario. I am using prepared statement where in query I am using in clause. So in clause do have dynamic values so I don't know how many ? should I put there. I can make it dynamic, but it will not be a good code. So someone suggested me to use temp table. But the same query could be used by multiple logins where each user could have their own values for in param. So how can it behave in that situation?

Comment: @santu - you can do that. As long as you populate the temporary table and call the statement from the same session, the call will only see the data you just put there. Multiple sessions could simultaneously have their own private data with no conflicts. But that's more of a SQL Server approach I think; you could also look at populating an array or a PL/SQL table depending on where you're generating the values and calling this from (PL/SQL, Java, ...). Or if the values come from another table you should be joining directly, not using any temporary structure.

Answer (score 0):

Given below are some points why and when we should temporary table :-

1)Temporary tables are created for storing the data in a tabular form, for easy retrieval of it when needed, with in that particular session.

2)It also add a security purpose of keeping the data available only for that particular session.

3) When a code goes long and a lot of cursors are opened it better to put the data in a temporary table so that it can be easily fetched at the time needed.